# linux + wget + print the files from URL address using login and password

Tags: linux, wget

I have the following URL address and need login/password in order to login

https://gt.dsdckdhdb.com/

after we login we can see files there

how with wget command we can see the files from the URL address using login and password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wget http://<username>:<password>@gt.dsdckdhdb.com/`

or

`wget --user <user> --password <password> http://gt.dsdckdhdb.com/`.

Comment: another question how to see only the files under the URL address?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @yael if you have another question, please open another question. Do not ask other things in comments.